# c# unit tests using sockets

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sockets

I'm trying to figure out how to write unit tests for a server application that requieres sockets in C#. I need to read from a socket in order to proccess the request. In Java I could avoid sockets by using Streams, so when writing unit tests i could easily convert a string into a stream.

```
// ====== Input ======
InputStream socketInputStream = new InputStream(socket.getInputStream()); 
// or using string instead like this
InputStream socketInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("string".getBytes());

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketInputStream));

// ====== Output ======
OutputStream socketOutputStream = new OutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
// I need to write byte[] to the stream
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socketOutputStream);
```

I only found NetworkStream() but it also requires a socket.

How can I achieve this in C# so i can create Streams without sockets?
And how can I write to a Stream and read it again to see if the message is correct?

Comment: Perhaps [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), which is backed by a byte[]. If you want to write a string and you are OK to "hard code" an encoding you could use something like [Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to convert the string to a byte[]

Comment: if it is backed by byte[] how can i use it, to read from a socket? the program has to be able to get a stream no matter if its created by string or socket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[nkvu - Moving this out of the comments and into the answer based on the poster's question against my comment; not trying to steal @Andrey's thunder]

So in Java you are doing:

```
InputStream socketInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("string".getBytes());
```

In your unit tests (I am assuming, based on your original question).

In C# you could do:

```
Stream socketInputStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("string"));
```

That would be (noting I haven't done real-world Java for a while) a C#-ish equivalent. Because MemoryStream is just a subclass of [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) you can use the general Stream methods to read data from it (e.g. Read()).

You could also write to a MemoryStream, e.g:

```
bytes[] toWrite = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Write to stream");
Stream writeToStream = new MemoryStream();
writeToStream.Write(toWrite, 0, toWrite.Length);
```

HTH, Nathan

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) in C#.